# VBA - Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stock in this code, Subscript out of range error i think it's because the number is too big`(LBound(DataArr, 20)`?

```
 For i = LBound(DataArr, 20) To UBound(DataArr, 20) 'change 1->2
        DataArr(i, 86) = "" 'change 3->4 '86
    Next i
```

> For i = LBound(DataArr, 20) To UBound(DataArr, 20) 'change 1->2

Above is my line error if i used `LBound(DataArr, 20)` *Subscript out of range* error but if i  use `LBound(DataArr, 1)` or 2 or 3 it's working..
but the column i'm going to count is in `Column T = 20` is there any other way?

My Full Code:(edited)

```
Public Sub Selection()

Dim file2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet, data(), i&
Dim myRangeColor As Variant, myRangeMonthValue
Dim MstrSht As Worksheet
Dim DataArr As Variant
Dim ColorArr As Variant
Dim MonthCol As Collection
Dim CloseToDate As Date
Dim MaxDate As Date
Dim c As Long


Set Sheet2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)
Set Sheet5 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox5.Text).Sheets(1)


DataArr = Sheet2.Range("A2:CI" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 'change 1->2

'Find distinct colors
ColorArr = ReturnDistinct(Sheet2.Range("T2:T" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)) 'change a->b 1->2

'Remove any values in the arrays third column
For i = LBound(DataArr, 1) To UBound(DataArr, 1) 'change 1->2
    DataArr(i, 86) = "" 'change 3->4 '86
Next i

'Loop Each Color
For c = LBound(ColorArr) To UBound(ColorArr)
    Set MonthCol = New Collection
    MaxDate = 0
    For i = LBound(DataArr, 1) To UBound(DataArr, 1) 'change 1->2
        If DataArr(i, 1) = ColorArr(c) Then 'change 1->2
            'Load the colors months into a collection
            On Error Resume Next
            MonthCol.Add Month(DataArr(i, 71)), CStr(Month(DataArr(i, 71))) 'change 2->3
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Find Max Date
            If DataArr(i, 71) Then 'change 2->3
                MaxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MaxDate, DataArr(i, 71)) 'change 2->3
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'If the color were found in three or more seperate months then the row with date closest to CloseToDate gets flagged
    If MonthCol.Count > 2 Then
        For i = LBound(DataArr, 1) To UBound(DataArr, 1) 'change 1->2
            If DataArr(i, 1) = ColorArr(c) And DataArr(i, 71) = MaxDate Then 'change 1->2 2->3
                DataArr(i, 86) = "1" '86
                DataArr(i, 87) = "1" '87
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next c

'Print results to sheet
Sheet2.Range("A2:CI" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = DataArr 'change 1->2

Function ReturnDistinct(InpRng As Range) As Variant
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim DistCol As New Collection
    Dim DistArr()

    'Add all values to collection
    For Each Cell In InpRng
        On Error Resume Next
        DistCol.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next Cell

    'Write collection to array
    ReDim DistArr(1 To DistCol.Count)
    For i = 1 To DistCol.Count Step 1
        DistArr(i) = DistCol.Item(i)
    Next i

    ReturnDistinct = DistArr
End Function
```

Comment: Use `UBound` and `LBound` with `1` or `2` as the second argument for the number of rows or the number of columns (in this order).

Answer (score 4):

> For i = LBound(DataArr, 20) To UBound(DataArr, 20) 'change 1->2

You are asking Excel, "what is the lower and upper bound for the 20th rank in DataArr?"

The problem is -- and the reason for the subscript out of range error -- that there is no 20th rank in DataArr. DataArr does in fact only contain 2 ranks. Which means that the LBound and UBound expressions raise errors, since they are being called with invalid arguments.

I am not exactly sure what rank you need to access, but the `20` is what you have to change - and the way your array is set up right now, that number must be either 1 or 2.

EDIT: For your leisure, here is a quick utility written by [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) that lets you programmatically verify the number of ranks in an array:

```
Private Function NumberOfArrayDimensions(arr As Variant) As Integer
' By Chip Pearson
Dim Ndx As Integer
Dim Res As Integer
On Error Resume Next
    Do
        Ndx = Ndx + 1
        Res = UBound(arr, Ndx)
    Loop Until Err.Number <> 0
NumberOfArrayDimensions = Ndx - 1
End Function
```

EDIT as per your comment:

> i want to count the data from column T that way i change it from 1 ->
>   20

I am not 100% on what you mean by this, but to access data from column T in the array (column number 20), this is the syntax:

```
someValue = DataArr(i, 20)
```

where `i` is (row number - 1) in this case.

For example, `DataArr(1, 20)` would contain the data from `Range("T2")` (or `Cells(2, 20)`)

EDIT as per your comments:

> this is what i'm trying but insted of columA it's columnT.. [My
>   logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125280/vba-count-values-within-a-certain-date-range)
>
> same result, but now i'm going to change the column instead of A it's
>   Column T and instead of B im comparing it with Column BS

Change

```
For i = LBound(DataArr, 20) To UBound(DataArr, 20) 'change 1->2
```

to

```
For i = LBound(DataArr, 1) To UBound(DataArr, 1) 'change 1->2
```

Because:

The first rank is your rows, the second rank is your columns. There's no 20th rank as previously discussed. Going by your description, it sounds like you need to set every cell inside column number 86 (which I guess is "BS") to nothing. In this case, the above change is correct.

Comment: i thought 20 = Column T? coz i want to count the data from column T that way i change it from 1 -> 20, i guess i to check the rank

Comment: I understand better now, but that is not the way to do it. When you define UBound in this way, you are asking for the 20th dimension of the array, not the 20th element inside one of the dimensions.

Comment: See my updated answer. I am not sure what you want to do - in your loop, do you want to count the number of non-empty cells in column T, as they appear inside your array?

Comment: this is what i'm trying but insted of columA it's columnT.. [My logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125280/vba-count-values-within-a-certain-date-range)

Comment: In that question, you are comparing column A with column B. If column A appears at least one time per month (as indicated in column B). What is the equivalent in this situation? What are you comparing column T with?

Comment: same result, but now i'm going to change the column instead of `A` it's `Column T` and instead of `B` im comparing it with `Column BS`..

Comment: do i need to use this ? _Private Function NumberOfArrayDimensions(arr As Variant) As Integer_

Comment: No. That was an auxiliary function to help you see how ranks work.

Comment: Make a new question. The issue is no longer a subscript error, nor is it that particular line of code. In the new question, include an example of how the data looks, what result you expect and what result you are actually getting.